# RGB value encoded from height

Tags: c++, colors, rgb

I have a program where I need to represent height as an RGBT (in float) value. That is:

```
[R, G, B, T (Transperancy)] -> [0.0f-1.0f, 0.0f-1.0f, 0.0f-1.0f, 0.0f-1.0f]
```

Conceptually I know that you can encode via basic height between max and min height. I even have some code for greyScale height encoding:

```
double Heightmin=0;
double Heightmax=23;

osg::Vec4 getColourFromHeight(double height, double alpha=1.0) {

    double r=(height-Heightmin)/Heightmax;
    double b=(height-Heightmin)/Heightmax;
    double g=(height-Heightmin)/Heightmax;
    return osg::Vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

What I would like to know, is if there is an algorithm that's more complex then just using R and G like this:

```
double r=(height-Heightmin)/Heightmax;
double b=0.0f;
double g=(Heightmax- height + Heightmin)/Heightmax;
```

(That is, the G is the inverted form of R, so at low values it will appear more green and at high values it will appear more red.

I would like to be able to utilise R G and B to give realistic looking hieght encoded landscapes:

[image]

This is an image of a 72dpi RGB height encoded topographic map. I would like to be able to achive something similar to this. Is there a simple algorithm to create an RGB value based on a minimum and maximum hieght?

Thaks for your help.

Ben

Comment: You just need to come up with a suitable [colour gradient](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=colour%20gradient&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=EMedT4OxJc7e8QPTsam8BQ&biw=1600&bih=775&sei=E8edT62BB4b98QOi5pmZDw) that you like, and then put it in a lookup table (or similar).

Comment: That sounds like a good idea but would it be suitable when considering the max and min height will be changing in the final code?

Comment: Are you sure that that image is only height encoded?  Seems to me like it's a combination of geographical and topographical data.

Comment: That isn't an image of my work, I was hoping to clarify the question by showing what sort of thing i wanted. You are correct though, water is shown as blue etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to come up with a suitable colour gradient that you like, and then put it in a lookup table (or similar).

Then all you need is something that will map a value in the range `min_height` -> `max_height` into the range `0` -> `255` (for example).

Of course, it's possible that you will find a colour gradient that can be expressed as mathematical functions, but that's less general.

Comment: I was hoping for a more general solution to the problem. But this is something i will try.

Comment: @Ben: Then what kind of thing were you hoping for?

Comment: To be honest, something similar to the equation given for grayScale Height encoding. But incorporating all the colours to make good looking terrain. I understand that this sort of thing may not exist, I am currently implementing your idea as this is also how it is done in matlab (not that it being your advice wasn't good enough, just someone at work informed me as well). I was just hoping it wpould be a little simpler.

Comment: If you just have height information that's not enough to derive a nice, natural color image of the terrain. You would need additional information such as vegetation, humidity, etc... to derive this. With height only the best you can do is assign a given color to a height via a color gradient function.

Comment: I managed to steal the lookup table from matlabs colour list. I have implemented this and it looks good thanks for the help.